# The schema blob was not uploaded to staging blob

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, system-error

I am getting the following error every now and then in data factory v2 during the execution of a Lookup activity that executes a Stored Procedure that is hosted in an AZ SQL database (serverless). The error appear randomly and I cannot find anything on the internet. Does someone know what might be happening?

> { "errorCode": "101", "message": "The schema blob was not uploaded to staging blob", "failureType": "SystemError", "target": "MergeTable - ForEachRawTable", "details": [] }

It does not occur always and when it does, I just rerun the pipeline and usually it goes away. There was one occasion where  I had to execute the pipeline like 3 times and then it went away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How's your flow in adf pipeline?I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: There is no way to add images here (I thought you could). Anyway, this the flow:
1. A lookup activity executes a SP to log the start datetime of the process.
2. A copy activity reads data from a table in an AZ SQL database (serverless) and inserts it in another table in the same database.
3. A lookup activity executes a SP that do a MERGE between 2 tables that are in the same AZ SQL database (serverless)

Comment: The error is not always there, it happens as well in others part of the process. For example, it has happened when a lookup activity that logs the start datetime of the process gets executed.

Is there a more specific log in ADF that might help me to have a better understanding on what's going on?

Thanks a lot!!!